# NetSuite : nlapiRemoveLineItem() issue if no value is selected in the list

Tags: netsuite

so we are facing this weird issue. There is a Customer list on the form which is of the type List/Record. On the basis of Customer selected in this list, I clear the transaction list on the child form using nlapiRemoveLineItem() call . Everything works well TILL the customer is selected properly in the customer list.

Now, lets say I just type customer name abc & it gets autopopulated without selecting it as such, in this case, the nlapiRemoveLineItem() on the other list fails miserably and simply adds new items in this list.

What is really happening here ? Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript runs asynchronously, which means if you call an event like loading the customer, the browser won't wait for the result to come back before it executes the next command, in this case the nlapiRemoveLineItem.

So the sequence of events that is happening goes:

1. Set the customer
2. Remove line items
3. Customer is loaded
4. Line items from customer are populated

And what you want is:

1. Set the customer
2. Customer is loaded
3. Line items from customer are populated
4. Remove line items

To achieve this you could either use a promise library like q (best way), make a while loop to wait for the customer to come back, or do it the lazy way and do a setTimeout and execute the line removal around the time you expect the customer to come back.